# Login Error in YII Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to the beautiful Yii Framework. So I am just going through the tutorials and documentation. So I am doing the blog tutorial from starting. So for blog application I made export the database from the blog folder which comes with Yii to MySQL. Again I decided to use Yii User module and for that I made export the user module database to MySQL. Now my problem is that when I am using login in the application it is showing some error like this

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I both tried  `index.php?r=site/login` and also `index.php?r=user/login`  both failed. So can some one tell me how to solve this. FYI in my database there are two fields like 'ia_user'  which is imported from the blog folder and 'ia_users' which is imported from the Yii User module folder. So is there any thing wrong. Below I am pasting the configuration of main.php file.

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
  'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
  'name'=>'My Blog Application',

  // preloading 'log' component
  'preload'=>array('log'),

  // autoloading model and component classes
  'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    /*user module starts here*/
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
    /*user module ends here*/
  ),

  'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
    /*
    'gii'=>array(
      'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
      'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
       // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
      'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
    */
  ),

  // application components
  'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
      // enable cookie-based authentication
      'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
      /*user module starts here*/
      'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
      /*user module ends here*/
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    /*
    'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      ),
    ),
    */
    //'db'=>array(
    //  'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    //),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
      'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tbl_blog',
      'emulatePrepare' => true,
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'tablePrefix'=> 'tbl_',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
      // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
    'log'=>array(
      'class'=>'CLogRouter',
      'routes'=>array(
        array(
          'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
          'levels'=>'error, warning',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
        /*
        array(
          'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
        ),
        */
      ),
    ),
  ),

  // application-level parameters that can be accessed
  // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
  'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
  ),
);
```

Please help me out.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.I asked help from Yii forum but not got any reply So I am asking for help here .

Comment: I literally know _nothing_ about this framework, but I see in the config this: `/*user module starts here*/ 'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),`, perhaps you could try: index.php?r=/user/login  -  but beyond that good luck!

Comment: The error you see should have a filename and line as well. Look into that code, locate the error. Then continue and find the place what is the cause of that error. Fix the cause. That's called debugging and the code you posted in your question is only a fraction of your site so it's hard to say. See as well [Trying to get property of non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304904/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)

Comment: Try to replace loginUrl "/user/login" to "user/login" ( no "/" symbol). And give more specific log message, because you should see where you couldn't get property of some object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add user in array of modules just like this

```
'user'=>array(
         'user'
      // enable cookie-based authentication
      'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
      /*user module starts here*/
      'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
      /*user module ends here*/
    ),
```